# Custom attribute saved but not loaded in collection?

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, collection

I added a custom attribute is_featured to my **Magento 1.7** store. Its a yes/no dropdown. I am setting it to yes on storeview level and to no on the standard level.

Now I try to load a collection with all the products that have is_featured set to yes. This is my code:

```
$products = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($products)->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'featured', 'eq' => '1')));
```

This only loads those products that have is_featured set to yes on both storeview and standard scope, the ones that have it set to yes on storeview only are NOT included. Why is this the case, did I miss something?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `addAttributeToSelect()` for add custom attribute in product collection :

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('your_custom_attribute_code')->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'is_featured', 'eq' => '1')));
```

Comment: It returns the right amount of products as it seems, but they do not have a name, SKU, image and so on. This is my code: `$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('featured')->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'featured', 'eq' => '1')));`

Comment: I also edited the code I am using in my OP.

Comment: You can set like addAttributeToSelect(array('*')) for all attribute display or addAttributeToSelect(array('name','sku'))

Comment: This is what works: `$products = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($products)->addAttributeToSelect('is_featured')->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'is_featured', 'eq' => '1')));
   `